# Passing parameters to a word macro from an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an issue a variable to a word app, via an excel macro:

```
dim wrdApp as Word.Application
dim wrdDoc as Word.Document
dim PRODUCT_NAME as string
PRODUCT_NAME="This thing"
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
wrdApp.Run "MAIN_TOC", PRODUCT_NAME
```

This generates Run-time error '450':
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the Word code for `MAIN_TOC"?

Comment: And therein lies the problem :( 
I hadn't set the word macro up properly. 
Once I made the proper declaration, the variable was passed:    
    Sub MAIN_TOC(PRODUCT As String)
    
Of course that broke the word macro but for totaly unrelated reasons.

Comment: I see. This is likely unanswerable without that information. Is the Word VBA project protected?

Answer (score 0):

As a background, I was processing multiple tables in Excel and passing the tables to Word, via the clipboard. 
I needed someway to let Word know what table I was passing. Using 'WrdApp.Run "MAIN_TOC", PRODUCT_NAME', I thought,
would allow Word to process each clipboard with the correct name. 
What in fact was happening, was that PRODUCT_NAME was passed but the contents of the clipboard was erased.

My eventual solution, was to place the name of the table, in the table itself. 
The word macro would get the clipboard and then look at the first cell of the table to get the table name.
When done, Excel then passed the next table and the process repeated.

All is working now.